# Trying to make a clickable table that changes a value in an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Disclaimer: This is my first post and I'm very new to coding. Trying my darndest to teach myself coding out of sheer interest and determination. Please let me know if anything in my code can be improved upon or if I should be doing things differently. Be gentle lol

Right now I'm working on a little project that a dev gave me to help me get the basics down. He had me create a 3x3 table and make it so when I click a square it turns black, and when its clicked again it turns back to white.

My next goal is to make an unordered list that has the color of each square written out and changes as the squares are clicked. Such as:

R1C1 is white......  ***click***......  R1C1 is black.

I've burnt a lot of grey matter over this and cant seem to figure it out. Ive tried approaching it in a lot of different ways to no avail. Thanks in advance for any and all help.

```css
td {
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding 2px
}

td.black-cell {
  background: black;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Game</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="game2css.css">
  <style>
      table {
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      border: 2px solid;
      padding: 10px;
     }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td onclick='myFunction()' id="top-left"> </td>
      <td id="top-middle"></td>
      <td id="top-right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="middle-left"></td>
      <td id="middle-middle"></td>
      <td id="middle-right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="bottom-left"></td>
      <td id="bottom-middle"></td>
      <td id="bottom-right"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <UL id="BWList">
    <li id="r1c1">Row 1, Column 1 is white.</li>
    <li id="r1c2">Row 1, Column 2 is white.</li>
    <li id="r1c3">Row 1, Column 3 is white.</li>
    <li id="r2c1">Row 2, Column 1 is white.</li>
    <li id="r2c2">Row 2, Column 2 is white.</li>
    <li id="r2c3">Row 2, Column 3 is white.</li>
    <li id="r3c1">Row 3, Column 1 is white.</li>
    <li id="r3c2">Row 3, Column 2 is white.</li>
    <li id="r3c3">Row 3, Column 3 is white.</li>
  </UL>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('td').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("black-cell");
      });
    });

    function myFunction() {
      var textnode = document.createTextNode("Black")
      var item =
        document.getElementById("r1c1").childNodes[0];
      item.replaceChild(textnode, item.childNodes[0]);
    }
    // I'm fairly positive this is the wrong approach but included it just to show one way that I
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9dwkhLyz/1/

Comment: There are many ways to do it, and since you are using jQuery already, you can use "class toggling" to achieve both tasks. You can assign the same class to one cell and its corresponding "description", while the visibility of the text "black/white" can be toggled along with the color of the cell. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: All the words make sense, and just you using them gives me a sense of direction, which may be just what I need to find a solution haha sometimes just knowing what to google is half the battle.

Comment: Depending on how much freedom you have to decide on the DOM structure of your HTML, you might want to mark the color in the `li`, so something like `Row 1, Column 1 is <span class="curcolor">white</span>.` That way you can target it with a jquery selector such as `$('#r'+row+'c'+col+' span.curcolor')`

Comment: @AutoEnigmatic Just made an update here: https://jsfiddle.net/9dwkhLyz/2/  quick and dirty, but it works :D

Comment: @AutoEnigmatic Added some explanation in my answer below. If you have question feel free to let me know.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this without the need of any ID's and/or complex code. Simply use `index()` to obtain the `li` you want to target and adjust the text using CSS and pseudo element.

```js
$('table td').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("black-cell");
  /*Get the index of the td within the tr +
    Get the index of the parent tr within the table*/
  var n = $(this).index() + $(this).parent().index() * 3;
  $('ul#BWList li').eq(n).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
}

td{
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding 2px
}

td.black-cell {
  background: black;
}

li:after {
  content: " white."
}

li.selected:after {
  content: " black."
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<ul id="BWList">
  <li>Row 1, Column 1 is</li>
  <li>Row 1, Column 2 is</li>
  <li>Row 1, Column 3 is</li>
  <li>Row 2, Column 1 is</li>
  <li>Row 2, Column 2 is</li>
  <li>Row 2, Column 3 is</li>
  <li>Row 3, Column 1 is</li>
  <li>Row 3, Column 2 is</li>
  <li>Row 3, Column 3 is</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow. This is such a clean answer. It amazes me how there is so many ways to attack the same task. Thanks for this.

Comment: Can you explain what's all happening in this line of code? Just to help me understand what makes it work?      

**var n = $(this).index() + $(this).parent().index() * 3;**

Comment: @AutoEnigmatic since we have 3 row and 3 colum to count the index we need to have column [index of td] + 3 * the row [index of tr ]

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick and dirty solution here: the idea is to have the same `id` and `class` names for a cell and its corresponding description. Then you can use the following code to get all the spans with the same class name as the Cell's `id`.

```
$("." + $(this).attr('id'))  //prepend a ".' to the ID
```

which is just like replacing "#r1c1" etc with ".r1c1", so the spans are selected. Then you can apply CSS class toggle.

You can also use jQuery to build the table and list, so that the code is cleaner.

```js
$(function() {
  $('td').click(function() {
    
    // Toggle cell style
    $(this).toggleClass("black-cell");
    
    $("." + $(this).attr('id')).each(function() {
  
      // toggle visibility of "black" and "white":
      $(this).toggleClass('hidden');

    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

td {
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding 2px
}

td.black-cell {
  background: black;
}

/* Hide the word "black" on load. */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Game</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="game2css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="r1c1"> </td>
      <td id="r1c2"></td>
      <td id="r1c3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="r2c1"></td>
      <td id="r2c2"></td>
      <td id="r2c3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="r3c1"></td>
      <td id="r3c2"></td>
      <td id="r3c3"></td>

    </tr>
  </table>
  <UL id="BWList">
    <li>Row 1, Column 1 is <span class="r1c1">white</span><span class="r1c1 hidden">black</span>.</li>
    <li>Row 1, Column 2 is <span class="r1c2">white</span><span class="r1c2 hidden">black</span>.</li>
    <li>Row 1, Column 3 is <span class="r1c3">white</span><span class="r1c3 hidden">black</span>.</li>
    <li>Row 2, Column 1 is <span class="r2c1">white</span><span class="r2c1 hidden">black</span>.</li>
    <li>Row 2, Column 2 is <span class="r2c2">white</span><span class="r2c2 hidden">black</span>.</li>
    <li>Row 2, Column 3 is <span class="r2c3">white</span><span class="r2c3 hidden">black</span>.</li>
    <li>Row 3, Column 1 is <span class="r3c1">white</span><span class="r3c1 hidden">black</span>.</li>
    <li>Row 3, Column 2 is <span class="r3c2">white</span><span class="r3c2 hidden">black</span>.</li>
    <li>Row 3, Column 3 is <span class="r3c3">white</span><span class="r3c3 hidden">black</span>.</li>
  </UL>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this and all your explanation. It has been very helpful.
EDIT: If i may ask, what does this line do exactly:

$("." + $(this).attr('id')).each(function() {

Comment: nvm sorry i re-read your original comment. It makes sense now.